# Can gdb's tui be divided into three windows?

Tags: gdb, tui

1. When I use gdb tui for debugging. I can use `layout spli`t to display the source code window and assembly window at the same time. But I also want to see the value of the register. If I use `layout regs` to display the register window, it will replace the source code window with the register window. Can I display source code, assembly code, and register windows at the same time?
2. When tui is displayed, I want to use the commands I used before. When I use the up and down arrow keys, the code window moves up and down. Is there any way to prevent me from re-entering the previously used commands?

Comment: Thank you. It is useful to use ctrl-p/ctrl-n to scroll the command line. But when I input a command, sometimes I input a wrong character, but if I want to use the left and right arrows to reach the wrong place, the code window still moves. Is there a method similar to ctrl-p/ctrl-n to move me left and right?

Comment: Yes, ctrl-b/ctrl-f for left/right, ctrl-a/ctrl-e for home/end.